# Braintree Lookup error 3d secured React Js / NodeJs Backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, braintree, credit-card

i have an react js web application and node js backend server.
I'm trying to accept 3d secured payment with credit card. I followed tutorial on braintree website, but still i have problem in "production mode".
In sandbox no problem, after inserted payment card details, 3d secured popup prompt and user can go forward.
In Production mode user never see 3D Secured. I'm using DROP-IN method.
"lookup_error" this is the error i received in log.

[image]

This is the flow: on loading webpage (checkout) i request to nodejs a client token, when i received it, i will render dropin. When user tap on confirm button i will call this method:

```
const requestPaymentMethod = await billing.istanceBraintree.requestPaymentMethod({threeDSecure:
                            {
                                amount: total.toString(),
                                email: user.email,
                                billingAddress: {
                                    givenName: user.nome, // ASCII-printable characters required, else will throw a validation error
                                    surname: user.cognome, // ASCII-printable characters required, else will throw a validation error
                                    phoneNumber: user.telefono,
                                    streetAddress: user.indirizzo,
                                    locality: user.citta,
                                    postalCode: user.cap,
                                    countryCodeAlpha2: user.stato.toString().substr(0, 2)
                                },
                                additionalInformation: {
                                    workPhoneNumber: user.telefono,
                                    shippingGivenName: user.nome,
                                    shippingSurname: user.cognome,
                                    shippingPhone: user.telefono,
                                    shippingAddress: {
                                        streetAddress: user.indirizzo,
                                        locality: user.citta,
                                        postalCode: user.cap,
                                        countryCodeAlpha2: user.stato.toString().substr(0, 2)
                                    }
                                },
                            }});
```

And the result is like screenshoot on top. I'm using last version of braintree drop-ui and web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in Braintree. I have contacted their and solved my problem.
This is the answer that received via email:

[image]